# wxPython GLCanvas Segfault

Tags: python, macos, opengl, wxpython, wxwidgets

GLCanvas is installed and imports, but it just segfaults when making the frame!

I'm just trying to run this example as-is: http://wiki.wxpython.org/GLCanvas

It fails at line 32, or self.canvas = glcanvas.GLCanvas(self, attribList=attribList)

I've tried reinstalling wxPython from source (unfortunately i can't do this too much because the heat right now makes compiling a little dangerous...) but no dice. For what it's worth, I think GL canvas is actually enabled, although I'm not sure what to check. I mean, it imports ok, and _glcanvas.so is in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/ .

Here are my stats:

- OS X version: 10.6.8
- Python: 2.7.6, installed from Homebrew
- wxPython: '3.0.0.0 osx-cocoa (classic)'
- Graphics card: ATI RadeonHD2400

Console dump: http://pastebin.com/t0kJnKDC

I know OpenGL works because I can run it from within pygame - I'm currently trying to port a game from pygame to wx, hence this issue.

Seems to me like the problem might be how wx was built, but I have no idea where to start debugging this...

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that it crashes inside `wxGLCanvas::Create()`, so the OpenGL support is definitely compiled in, otherwise you wouldn't have `wxGLCanvas` there at all. Unfortunately I have no idea about what happens there, notably there should be no way to end up inside `Reparent()` when creating the window. Maybe the function names are just off (because of missing debug info), or maybe something was indeed built incorrectly. I'm afraid you do need to compile it from source to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the 3.0.1.0 preview version fixed this issue - just a bug, thankfully.